# Submartingale and expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Assume $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a submartingale and $T_1$, $T_2$ are stopping times such that $P(T_2\leq k)=1$ and $P(T_1\leq k)=1$. Is it true that $E[X_{T_1}]$ and $E[X_{T_2}]$ are less than or equal to $E[X_k]$? My idea is that it is true.

Comment: Yes. This follows from the optional stopping theorem.

Comment: Thanks. But integrability of $X_{T_1}$ and $X_{T_2}$ would follow from the fact that when defining a martingale  we already start from integrable $X_i$, wouldn't it? @user7924249

Comment: Yes. Integrability is ensured as your stopping times are (almost surely) bounded.

Comment: Why does boundedness matter if $E[X_i]$ is finite for each $i$? @user7924249

Comment: Because stopping times in general can be quite strange. To my knowledge, the strongest version of optional stopping theorem in discrete time is for 'optional' stopping times, i.e. stopping times that satisfy that $\lbrace X_{\tau \wedge n}\mid n\in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ is uniformly integrable. 
I cannot come up with a counterexample just now, but I will comment one if I get the time. You can quite possibly construct a stopping time using indicator functions which is finite while not ensuring integrability.

Comment: Ok, so the optional stopping theorem is not required to deduce integrability of $X_{T_1}$ and $X_{T_2}$, but it is required to establish that $E[X_k]$ bounds their expectations from above. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.